Get script path of executed script in R
I am using R to create three scripts.
The script A.R contains the following code.
get_file_location <- function() {
  # Attempts to get the file path in RStudio
  if (interactive() && "rstudioapi" %in% rownames(installed.packages())) {
    return(rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path)
  }

  # Alternative to get the file path if source() is used
  this_file <- (function() { attr(body(sys.function(1)), "srcfile") })()

  # If the path cannot be retrieved (e.g., in the console without RStudio), assign a default value
  if (!is.null(this_file)) {
    return(this_file$filename)
  } else {
    return("File not specified or default path")
  }
}

code_name <- get_file_location() %>% str_split_1(., pattern = "/") %>% tail(., 1)

paste("Path of script A is: ", code_name )

Then I have my script B.R, which looks like this:
source("A.R")

And finally, I have my script C.R, which looks like this:
source("B.R")

What I need is to be able to run the script C.R from the R console or from the Linux terminal, and the expected result should be
source("C.R")
# Path of script A is: A.R

However, I am struggling to correctly handle the function calls between these scripts, and my result is
source("C.R")
# NULL

Any suggests

Not what you asked for, but what I think you'd benefit from would be the here package. https://github.com/jennybc/here_here

Curiously, why do you need to find the path of executing script? What is your larger problem? Automating an R solution? Remember when you call Rscript from command line, working directory is current path of shell.

1) If we knew that A.R, B.R and C.R are all in the getwd() directory then we could just use source in the three files as shown:
# --- A.R ---
path <- file.path(getwd(), "A.R")
print(path)

# --- B.R ---
source("A.R")

# --- C.R ---
source("B.R")

starting it off with
source("C.R")

or if they are not in the getwd() directory then setwd to it first or from command line change directory to the one they are all in before running the script.
2) If that is not acceptable but it is still the case that A.R, B.R and C.R are in the same directory then try this.path() and this.dir() from the this.path package as shown below.  We assume that A.R, B.R and C.R are all in the same directory and that they contain this:
# --- A.R ---
path <- this.path::this.path()
print(path)

# --- B.R ---
A.R <- file.path(this.path::this.dir(), "A.R")
source(A.R)

# --- C.R ---
B.R <- file.path(this.path::this.dir(), "B.R")
source(B.R)

and we start this off by running this or use whatever path is needed to get to C.R:
source("C.R") 

or run run the script from the command line.
3) See the this.path README for some alternatives.

If you know a function name (e.g. fn) in script A, just use utils::getSrcFilename(fn).  This depends on sourcing that file with keep.source=TRUE, which you can set to be the default.
